# Debugging "one line" methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

imagine (in header file):

```
int getInt() { return m_intValue; }
```

and

```
int getInt() 
{
    return m_intValue;
}
```

how can I debug first example, to see `m_intValue`?
In example 2, I can set breakpoint at line one, press F10(step over) and then see (after hovering `m_intValue`) what is in `m_intValue`. Or just add BP at `return m_intValue` line.

But when I place BP at line in first version, I can not see debug infos of `m_intValue`.

This example is just demonstrative. I know I can see value in place, where I call `getInt` (see as returning value). But in more complicated cases (e.g. returning value modified because of something going out of scope) I really want to see `m_intValue` in time of processing return.

Hope you understand my question.

Thank you!

Comment: In gcc you can pass the -fno-inline switch. Look for something similar in Microsoft's compiler

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question has nothing to do with `inline`, but to do with the fact that all three debuggable 'sequence points' are on the same source line.

Comment: @ildjarn: you are right, I have modified title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get the breakpoint set at the wrong code.  It breaks on the function entrypoint, the *this* variable won't be initialized yet.  You definitely want to favor the 2nd coding style if you want to debug these accessors.  Which you shouldn't, it doesn't have a bug.

If you *really* need to inspect the object with the code written in the 1st snippet then switch to disassembly view and single-step past the stack frame setup code.